I’m looking for a Sci-fi book where a man’s brain is hijacked by someone trying to prove what human consciousness and the soul is
I read it probably 15 or more years ago now, so it’s not new.
It is a book where a man’s brain is hijacked by someone trying to prove what human consciousness and the human soul is. He is kidnapped, operated on, and his brain is connected to electrodes that controls him both physically and emotionally. His kidnapper is proving that we have no souls and who we are, our soul, is merely neurons firing and we can be manipulated however he wants.
These two men I think were friends in the book, or they were at one time.
I’ve been haunted by this book ever since I read it. Please help me find it!
